# XSL : Putting multiple Apostrophes together

Tags: xslt

I am facing some challenges when trying to send Apostrophe in xml file

If there is an Apostrophe in the name field, put an escape sequence and send 2 apostrophes together

M'cDonald should be send as below

M''cDonald

Any idea how this can be achieved in XSL ?

Comment: Which version of XSLT/XPath?

Comment: Its XSL version  1.0.2

Comment: If your create a xslt variable `<xsl:variable naem='x'>M''cDonald</xsl:variable>` and than use it `<xsl:value-of select="$x" />` there should be no problem. But perhaps I did not got the question right.

Comment: Its not a constant , I mean names will be different for different persons. So just thinking if hardcording the name would help here?

Comment: If there is a Apotrophe in the name field, XML file should have 2 apostrophes -  if its A's then it should be A''s

Comment: There is no such thing as XSLT 1.0.2. If you're using XSLT 1.0, then you need a recursive template as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631190/xsl-replace-single-and-double-quotes-with-apos-and-quot/27633138#27633138